# Android 2.2.1 bug preventing browser-based geolocation?

Tags: android

On Android, users are getting error code "1" -- which is "permission denied."  However, the users I'm working with were never ASKED permission by the browser for geolocation.

I've tried calling getCurrentPosition with and without "enableHighAccuracy" but the error is the same regardless.

Anyone experienced this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map, handle_error)
}
function show_map(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        if (document.myform) {
            document.myform._lat.value = latitude;
            document.myform._lon.value = longitude;
        }
}
function handle_error(err) {
  alert('Error code: ' + err.code + ' Could not get your location.');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may vary depending on which ROM one is using, but there's an option in my browser to enable location requests.  If it is unchecked, all location requests are ignored with no prompt.  Could that be what's happening to your users?

Comment: Nah, they've got it checked.  That's what is puzzling me.

Comment: @Dan: Are your users accessing the site from the browser itself, or from a WebView? If it's in a WebView, some [special steps are required](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7176) - for instance, the app itself must have the permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

Comment: Nope, it's from the stock Android browser.

Comment: @Dan: That's very strange indeed.  I created a Fiddle using your code (modified very slightly for simplicity) and tested it on my Android browser - it worked perfectly.  [Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/uFzSH/), if you'd like to take a look.  I'm running 2.3, though, so maybe this _is_ a version specific problem.  The only other information I found was [this](http://www.mobilehtml5.com/post/1276879531/android-2-2-browser-geolocation-gotcha), but you said you'd already tried with `enableHighAccuracy`... Did you refresh the browser in between tries to ensure you weren't getting a cached script?

Comment: Additionally, since that link says that `enableHighAccuracy` is required, maybe you could post the _exact_ code you used when you had it set to `true`?

Comment: It's pretty vanilla:
`code`
if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map, handle_error,{enableHighAccuracy:true});
}
`code`

Returning that same error code.